# a concept similar to pointers in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, pointers, reference

Is there a concept of pointers or anything similar to that in as3?

I have used a concept of

```
var mc1:MovieClip;
var mc2:MovieClip();
var mcCommon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcCommon["myptr"] = mc1;
mcCommon["myptr"] = mc2;
```

Where would I get to read and learn more about this concept. I'd like to get simple answers, as I am not an expert in as3. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking specifically about the code, first of all it should look like this:

```
var mc1:MovieClip;
var mc2:MovieClip;
var mcCommon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcCommon["myptr"] = mc1;
mcCommon["myptr"] = mc2;
```

Though both mc1 and mc2 are actually null.

The syntax mcCommon["myptr"] means that you create a property named "myptr" on MovieClip mcCommon. So you can later retrieve the content of this property using mcCommon["myptr"]. The last line actually overwrites the content of the property (if it wasn't null of course). You can do that because MovieClip class is dynamic. On other (non-dynamic) instances you can't create properties like this.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't coded in a language that specifically uses pointers in a while, and I'm not sure this is exactly what you're asking, but here's an attempt at answering your question:

In AS3, a variable reference to Objects are always pointers, with the exception of basic types (Strings, Numbers, ints, and Booleans), which are always by-value only.

So, for basic types, you get a "by-value" behavior:

```
var a:String = "hello";
var b:String = a;  // b is a new String, a clone of a
b += " world";
trace(a);  // hello
trace(b);  // hello world
```

A modification to b did not modify the a variable.  Or perhaps it could be said that a and b were references to the same String after line 2, but the += operator created a new String and assigned it to b.  If you look at the [String documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html), note that none of the member functions actually modify the String in-place, they all return new Strings.

You'll see the same behavior with function calls with simple, non-pointer parameters:

```
function wont_modify(word:String):String
{
  word += " world";
  return word;
}
var a:String = "hello";
trace(wont_modify(a));  // hello world
trace(a); // hello
```

However, for non-simple types, access is by-reference (what is referred to as a pointer in other languages):

```
var a:Array = [1, 2, 3];
var b:Array = a;  // b is now a reference to a
b.push(4);
trace(a);  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
trace(b);  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want a "pointer-like" behavior for a simple type like a String, it must be a member of a pointer-like Object, for which you pass a reference around:

```
function will_modify(obj:Object):void
{
  obj.a += " world";
}
var obj:Object = { a:"hello" }
will_modify(obj);
trace(obj.a);  // hello world
```

Strings and Numbers actually do actually extend Object, but all the operators and function calls treat them by-value and not by-reference.

Comment: +1 for the answer concerning parameter passing by-reference . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although not the same thing, I think what you are looking for is a [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html), where every property in the collection has a `String` as a key which it can be accessed through.

Comment: Not exactly: you can use non-String keys.