# Accessing a variable itself rather than the value of the variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

A problem I've been running into lately involves trying to change a variable indirectly.

e.g.

```
 var health:int = 100;
 var currentVar = health; //I want currentVar to equal "health"

 var currentVar -= 50; // I want to subtract 50 from health;
 trace(health) // 100
```

I could set health to equal currentVar afterward, but this is not possible in some situations.
How can I make as3 understand I don't want current var to equal what health equals, but health itself?

Comment: Why do you have currentVar if you want to manipulate health directly?

Comment: I think this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982970/a-concept-similar-to-pointers-in-as3. But you may want to step back and rethink the the problem. I often find when I am trying to do things like this, I am solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Because I want to do the same manipulations on different vars in different situations. Sometimes currentVar equals health, sometimes it equals Mana (<--- for example: Not really what I am doing)

Comment: I looked at the link, and I'm not sure it solves this for me. Maybe I'm not getting it. These are movieClips, I just want to access a var:int

Comment: Like a getVarByName() kind of thing. lol. Is this not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is. Without putting the var in a dictionary or as a member of an object. Primitives in AS3 are cloned when assigned not stored as a reference. From http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/data-types.html "Note: For readers interested in the technical details, ActionScript 3 stores primitive values internally as immutable objects. The fact that they are stored as immutable objects means that passing by reference is effectively the same as passing by value"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a reference (or pointer) to a basic type in As3. 
They are always passed by value.

But you can do this with objects for example.
In your case, an object oriented approach is probably better anyway.
Who's health is it? Who's mana is is?
It's probably one thing that has both mana and health (and probably many other properties)

So whatever function is trying to modify different properties, should receive the whole object instead.
You can (should) define a class that contains all those properties with according setter and getter functions.
Than accept that class as a parameter.
Within that function you can decide what property to modify.

Here's one example how that could look like:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.AVM1Movie;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class FlashTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function FlashTest() 
        {
            var hero:Hero = new Hero();

            trace(hero.health, hero.mana);
            dealDamage(hero);

            trace(hero.health, hero.mana);
            absorbEnergy(hero);

            trace(hero.health, hero.mana);
            doRandomThing(hero);
        }

        private function dealDamage(hero:Hero):void
        {
            hero.health -= 5;
        }

        private function absorbEnergy(hero:Hero):void
        {
            hero.mana -= 5;
        }

        private function doRandomThing(hero:Hero):void
        {
            if (Math.random() >= 0.5)
            {
                hero.health -= 15;
            }
            else
            {
                hero.mana -= 15;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class Hero
{
    private var _health:uint = 100;
    private var _mana:uint = 100;

    public function set health(value:uint):void
    {
        _health = Math.max(0, value);

        if(_health == 0)
        {
            trace("I'm dead");
        }
    }

    public function get health():uint
    {
        return _health;
    }

    public function set mana(value:uint):void
    {
        _mana = Math.max(0, value);

        if(_mana == 0)
        {
            trace("No more magic");
        }
    }

    public function get mana():uint
    {
        return _mana;
    }
}
```